# How to diagnose / troubleshoot gradle build not running dependency task?

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, multi-project

I'm adding `gradle` to a multi-project build and hitting the learning curve.

I need to invoke a custom task of `type:Exec` before compilation of a subproject. The task is not invoked. Why?

### build.gradle of parent project

```
task precompiletask(type:Exec) {
    println "Executing pre-compile task"
    // ...
}

task(":cppproj:build").dependsOn precompiletask

// Also tried this, same output
//project(":cppproj").task(":build").dependsOn precompiletask

// Also tried this -> error "Cannot add task 'build' as a task with that name already exists"; why on Earth would this syntax *add* the task "build"?
//project(":cppproj").task("build").dependsOn precompiletask // I also tried this
```

### build.gradle of subproject 'cppproj'

```
apply plugin: "cpp"

model {
    components {
        api(NativeLibrarySpec) {
            sources {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### -

---

### Related questions

Why do I find it so hard to debug this? I am running `gradle` with the verbose-est output (`gradle build --debug --warning-mode all`). The only mentions of my custom task `precompiletask` are these, clustered towards the beginning of the output:

```
07:24:41.151 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Realize task :precompiletask' started
07:24:41.243 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Realize task :precompiletask'
07:24:41.243 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Realize task :precompiletask' completed
07:24:41.249 [QUIET] [system.out] Executing pre-compile task
```

Why no errors related to failing to link the two tasks using `dependsOn`? Since `dependsOn` is clearly invoked in my code I'd expect an error that either the subproject or tasks are not found, or dependsOn itself fails somehow. Does this have to do with `gradle`'s flexibility of being able to refer to stuff that doesn't exist yet?

What does it mean to 'Realize task' anyway? Could not find this documented. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the gradle command you use to execute your build ( which tasks are you invoking exactly ) and the output result (it should list all executed tasks) ;  and which version of gradle are you using ?

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Thanks. It is `gradle build --debug --warning-mode all`. My root project has a C++ sub-project (`apply plugin: "cpp"`) and a Java sub-project (`apply plugin: 'java-library'`). I'm trying to add a a code-generation step (`precompiletask`) that precedes the compilation of the two sub-projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the proper way to access the *:cppproj:build* task in your root project build: you are using  [project.task()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:task(java.lang.String)) methods , which is actually creating a new task.

You have several ways available to 'locate' the task you want to configure (adding the dependsOn constraint), as explained here : [locating tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:locating_tasks)

In your case you could write:

```
tasks.getByPath(':cppproj:build').dependsOn precompiletask
```

Note 1:

When using the syntax `task(":cppproj:build").dependsOn precompiletask`: you create a new task named ':cppproj:build' on the root project and make it depend on precompiletask: that's why *precompiletask* is not executed if you execute *build* tasks from parent or subproject.

Note 2:

> // Also tried this -> error "Cannot add task 'build' as a task with that name already exists"; why on Earth would this syntax *add* the task "build"?
>   //project(":cppproj").task("build").dependsOn precompiletask

=> because the `project.task(String)` method  creates a task, so you are trying to add new task named *build* to the subproject which already have one *build* task.

Comment: So the method `project.task(String)` **adds** a task, OK - thanks for clarifying that. Your suggestion puts me on the right track - I now get my `precompiletask` executed. As an aside, please could you tell me why this alternative syntax fails? `//project("cppproj").tasks["build"].dependsOn precompiletask` (it fails with _Task with name 'build' not found in project ':cppproj'_). The task is clearly there, cause it works by only switching to your `getByPath()` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding an answer to my sequel question: why does this seemingly equivalent syntax fail to achieve the same thing: `project("cppproj").tasks["build"].dependsOn`.

I found that the "configuration" step of gradle build is done by default in a top-down manner, meaning when the root project build.gradle is executed, the subprojects don't contain their tasks yet. This can be changed by doing:

```
evaluationDependsOnChildren()
```

... and then one can write:

```
subprojects.each {
    it.tasks["build"].dependsOn myPreCompileTask
}
```